# How to add unsubscribe link as shows in below image

Tags: c#, email, smtp, gmail, list-unsubscribe

I've written code in C# that send mail to number of users. The email is in HTML format and contains a unsubscribe link.

What I want to do is, have unsubscribe link as shown in image... 
    [image: enter code here]

To add more information, I'm using SendGrid for sending emails to end users.

I viewed raw message format in Gmail and I can see Header there in format

```
List-unsubscribe: <https..../usersettings?SubscriberId=VioR5IcgvSIosfB1w%2FCPfhpyGBdko%2BxsmFTAsQAemuWgSJkpTP1UeDg%2BW4frl59A0KVVpiK0lI7IrS3N1BCm0Sspd0dqEaJGlKHAY3g7IR3INwkyJEAmfU55TBJ8uEo%3D>
```

Yet the link is not displayed. What am I missing?

Comment: https://www.zettasphere.com/gmail-email-unsubscribe-header/

Comment: @Thomas - Even after adding list-unsubscribe header, GMAIL is not showing that link!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add that link in your email header something like this

```
mailMessage.Headers.Add("List-Unsubscribe", String.Format(
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "<http://{0}>", unSubscribeUrl));
```

Comment: OK, Let me try this

Comment: It is the syntax, I haven't tried. Whats you output of using this?

Comment: No success with this... is header name case senstivive? I tried list-unsubscribe and unsubscribe header

Comment: It seems google only shows this link if end user won't open sent mail to often.
Also it requires correction. Header name is 'List-Unsubscribe' instead of unsubscribe.